# ¿Porque el registro se inserta pero el campo imagen en la base de datos mysql no muestra nada?

Tags: java, mysql, web

**Corregirme porfavor si hay algun problema en mi pregunta**
Quisiera consultarles si me pueden ayudar con mi problema.
Tengo una base de datos con los campos idProducto, nombre, img ...etc.
Estoy usando Dao, y tengo un archivo jsp llamado Producto.jsp del cual saco toda la información, a continuación proporciono el input de donde saco la información de la imagen.

```html
<div class="btn btn-dark btn-sm float-left">
<span>Elija una imagen</span>
<input type="file" name="txtImagen" accept="image/*">
Dar click en el boton seleccionar para habilitar
</div>
```

y dicho input esta dentro de un form con los siguientes atributos:

```html
<form action="ProcesarA" method="POST" name="frmProducto" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Como se ve, lo envio a un servlet llamado ProcesarA el cual les muestro a continuación:

```java
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        //instancias
        DaoProducto dao = new DaoProducto();
        Producto p = new Producto();
        Categoria c = new Categoria();
        Proveedor pv = new Proveedor();
        RequestDispatcher rd=null;
        try {
            p.setIdProducto(0);            
            p.setNombre(request.getParameter("txtNombre"));
            Part pt = request.getPart("txtImagen");//Aca empieza el seteo de la imagen
            InputStream inS = pt.getInputStream();
            p.setImg(inS);
            p.setPrecio(Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("txtPrecio")));
            p.setDescripcion(request.getParameter("txtDesc"));
            p.setStock(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtStock")));
            p.setEstado(1);
            c.setIdCategoria(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("categoria")));
            p.setCategoria(c);
            pv.setIdProveedor(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("proveedor")));
            p.setProveedor(pv);
            if (request.getParameter("btnAgregar")!=null) {
            dao.insertarProducto(p);      
            
            }
            
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Producto.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            request.setAttribute("Error", e);
            
        }
    }
```

Y luego como se puede ver los datos los envia al metodo insertarProducto, el cual el codigo es este:

```java
//Insertar producto
    public void insertarProducto(Producto p) throws Exception{
        try {
            this.conectar();
            String sql ="INSERT INTO producto values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = this.getCon().prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setInt(1, 0);
            pst.setString(2, p.getNombre());
            pst.setBlob(3, p.getImg());
            pst.setDouble(4, p.getPrecio());
            pst.setString(5, p.getDescripcion());
            pst.setInt(6, p.getStock());
            pst.setInt(7, 1);
            pst.setInt(8, p.getCategoria().getIdCategoria());
            pst.setInt(9, p.getProveedor().getIdProveedor());
            //Ejecutando query
            pst.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }finally{
            this.desconectar();
        }
    }
```

Mi problema es que si inserta los demas campos pero en el campo de imagen cuando reviso la base de datos no hay ningun archivo blob en ese registro, les doy un ejemplo de como inserta el registro:

```
18              //Este es el idProducto
Vino barato     //Nombre
                //Aca deberia estar un registro como este: [BLOB - 27.7 KB] pero no aparece nada
5.99            //este es el precio
Vino economico  //descripcion
5               //stock
1               //estado
5               //idCategoria
9               //idProveedor
```

Espero puedan ayudarme con mi primer pregunta. De antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Es muy probable que la imagen no este llegando al servlet. Aunque no pones el encabezado del servlet es muy probable que le falte la anotación `@MultipartConfig`.
Seria de este modo:

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
@MultipartConfig
public class ProcesarA extends HttpServlet {//...
```

Esa anotación le dice al servlet que hay partes adjuntas y sin ella no puedes usar las funciones como `request.getPart("txtImagen");` ya que aunque no te lanzan excepción por falta de la anotación, no funcionan correctamente.

Comment: Buenas tardes y muchas gracias por responder mi pregunta. Justamente me asegure de que tenia la anotación @MultipartConfig y la importación antes de hacer la pregunta. Actualmente si la tengo, lo que me llamo la atención cuando debugie mi proyecto es que si llena la variable img de mi objeto p con un ByteArray. A continuación te muestro una imagen de lo que me refiero: https://ibb.co/8xL5ZkJ  Estoy realmente confundido.

Comment: y ya probaste con otras funciones que guardan Blob?? por ejemplo convierte el input stream a un arreglo de bytes y seteando con setBytes. Esto porque algunas funciones solo funcionan con ciertas bases de datos.

Comment: Vi por ahí un metodo que ocupaba la ruta del archivo pero según no se puede por cuestiones de seguridad. Y acabo de hacer lo que me has dicho, primero converti el inputStream con este metodo que encontre: `byte[] buf = IOUtils.readFully(inS, -1, false);`  y con eso tambien tuve que cambiarle el tipo a  la variable img de InputStream a byte[], pero sigue sin funcionar , me guarda los otros registros pero no la imagen.

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArray); oos.writeObject(inS);                                                                                       
byte[]a= byteArray.toByteArray();` Acabo de encontrar esto, no se si voy por el camino correcto pero quitando `oos.writeObject(inS)` me inserta un blob! pero al parecer es como un array por defecto porque solo pesa 4B es un peso diferente a la imagen que realmente subo